# What is it with Google sites taking forever to load in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I was trying to access my gmail earlier and after about 20 minutes looking at the little progress bar thing in the middle of the screen, I gave up, loaded IE11 and got into my inbox almost instantly.

Now I've done what I needed to do, Google searches, Webmaster Tools, Analytics, Calendar and pretty much everything except YouTube is again taking forever to load up – but ONLY in Chrome.

It gets better, in my Network tab under Dev tools, I noticed that the actual fetch for the webpage when I was accessing my gmail failed with an `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` although the Response failed to load.

- I'm running Windows 8.1
- My version of Chrome is Version 44.0.2403.89 m although I was using 43 until I tried posting this and the problem was in 43 as well
- Chrome add-ons I have installed are

  - Avast Online Security
  - Adblock Plus
  - Reddit Enhancement Suite
  - Do Not Track
- My brother is now reporting similar issues with Google sites

  - My brother's system is
  - Windows 7 Pro
  - He's using Version 43x of Chrome
  - He's using the following extensions

    - Adblock Plus
    - Avast

**Other considerations**

- Google sites load fine with full functionality when I use IE11 (the version that comes with Windows)
- Oddly enough, this problem seems specific to Chrome as Firefox doesn't replicate it
- [I've used incognito mode to test without addons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XdpM.png)
- I don't enable flash as a rule unless its for something I'm using at the time in which case I manually opt to run flash for that website alone
- I'm not using a proxy or any "middle-man" on my internet connection but for a 100gbps switch into which my lan cable is plugged. This switch is connected to my internet router. No I'm not willing to plug my computer directly into the router because the cabling is delicate (its not a great setup) and I would risk inadvertently powering everything down

So what's going on here? Is this a problem with my internet connection (if so, why isn't every site affected) or is it something to do with Google?

Here are the Response Headers:

```
alternate-protocol:443:quic,p=1
cache-control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-encoding:gzip
content-security-policy:script-src https://*.talkgadget.google.com/
'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://hangouts.google.com/
https://talkgadget.google.com/
https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/installedApps/
https://www-gm-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/js/
https://docs.google.com/static/doclist/client/js/
https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/ https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/
https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api https://ssl.google-analytics.com/
https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/ https://apis.google.com/js/
https://clients1.google.com/complete/
https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/
https://ssl.gstatic.com/inputtools/js/
https://ssl.gstatic.com/cloudsearch/static/o/js/
https://www.gstatic.com/feedback/js/
https://www.gstatic.com/common_sharing/static/client/js/
https://www.gstatic.com/og/_/js/;frame-src
https://*.talkgadget.google.com/ https://www.gstatic.com/mail/intl/
'self' https://accounts.google.com/ https://apis.google.com/u/
https://apis.google.com/_/streamwidgets/
https://clients6.google.com/static/
https://content.googleapis.com/static/
https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/
https://www.google.com/calendar/ https://docs.google.com/
https://drive.google.com
https://*.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/
https://feedback.googleusercontent.com/resources/
https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/
https://*.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/ifr
https://hangouts.google.com/ https://talkgadget.google.com/
https://isolated.mail.google.com/ https://mail-settings.google.com/
https://www-gm-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/
https://plus.google.com/ https://wallet.google.com/gmail/
https://www.youtube.com/embed/
https://clients5.google.com/pagead/drt/dn/
https://clients5.google.com/ads/measurement/jn/
https://www.gstatic.com/mail/ww/
https://clients5.google.com/webstore/wall/
https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/ https://apis.google.com/additnow/
https://www.gstatic.com/mail/promo/;object-src
https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/swfs/
https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/;report-uri
/mail/cspreport
content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:Wed, 22 Jul 2015 13:18:27 GMT
expires:Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma:no-cache
server: GSE
status:200
strict-transport-security:max-age=10886400; includeSubdomains
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-dns-prefetch-control:off
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

Comment: The next step.  Find any build of Chrome v43 and see if this is something introduced in v44.

Comment: Well I was actually using 43 when I posted this... It was just for this question and my claim that I was using the latest version that I checked at which time Chrome updated, so I can confirm it's still there in 43

Comment: You have tried a 100% virgin profile?  I know you have tried incognito mode without success.  I also assume Chrome did work for you in the past.  Do you have any other machine you can use to verify perhaps this isn't a specific configuration problem of the machine your using?

Comment: Actually its a fairly recent problem. I do have another profile that I can try with which is... Well it isn't new, but I hardly ever use it. I will check on my laptop with this profile to see what happens. That at least would seem to narrow it down to something with my desktop

Comment: Given your brother and you both seem to be Avast users I would look at that.  If I were a betting man, I bet both of you, use a version of Avast with web security.  This feature uses a SSL MiTM type feature to protect even https content, Google is very protective over its certificates, this can basically cause alot of problems if they are being forged by Avast.  Google Chrome has built-in protection against this type of thing, Firefox and IE will respect the system's certificates, Chrome will respect other certificates but just be protective of Googles.

Comment: *Every single one of the problem sites is a secure website.*

Comment: _No reason to downvote..._

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to try:

- Uninstall/reinstall Chrome.  It could be a faulting library, could be an application hang, could be any number of issues in the application.  A reinstall would rule out a lot of these
- Try disabling addons.  Addons can affect the way a browser works.  They can make changes to the way a browser loads/renders/displays a webpage and this can have an affect on page loads
- Check/Disable and proxy settings or at leat ensure they are set to the same as IE/Firefox/whatever else you're running.  Its possible that your browser is timing out trying to reach a non-contactable proxy
- Clear all caches.  If your browser is storing corrupt cached data, it can theoretically take a while for the corrupt cache image/script etc to faulter and a fresh copy to be requested
- Disable Flash.  Probably not the cause, but known to make Chrome/Firefox run very slowly.
- Create a new profile.  Just good practise when debugging browser problems

Hopefulyl one of these will help